# Display notification message onsave data to DB in MVC4 VB.NET using razor

Tags: jquery, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to display a notification messge to the user when he click save button on the page.
This save button will call a Click event in Jquery and then am calling an Ajax function inside that event. In that ajax call am 
calling my action method in controller which is a HttpPost method.
When the data is posted to data am returning an integer value( 1 for success, 0 for failure).
Based on this I need to display a message to the user.How to do this ?

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (e) {
            var vComments = $("#ddlComments :selected").text();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Acc/Save",
                type: "POST",
                data: vComments,
                success: function (data) { },
                error: function (ex) { alert(ex.responseText); }
            });
        });
```

Controller:

```
<httppost>
Function Save(ByVal comments as String) as actionResult
    dim result as int32 = save(comments)
if result = 1 Then
    'I need to display a notification saying successfully posted
else
    ' I need to display a notification "Unable to post"
End If
End Function
```

Comment: return `Content(...)` what you're looking for? Also, if this is AJAX you should probably be returning `JsonResult` and return an object (e.g. `{error:false}` and `{error:true,errorMessage:"Something went wrong"}` then check `data.error` in your success callback.)

Comment: is that - return Content("Posted data successfully to DB") ? If yes how can I handle this in the view to display to the user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it (and varying from my original comment) I would suggest taking advantage of [`HttpStatusCodeResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg401958%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in your action:

```vb
<httppost>
Function Save(ByVal comments as String) as actionResult
    dim result as int32 = save(comments)
    if result = 1 Then
        Return new HttpStatusCodeResult(204) ' 204 Successful, No Content
    else
        Return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500) ' Error, Internal Server
    End If
End Function
```

Now you can rely on `error` and `success` callbacks to display the appropriate message.

Comment: ok. how to handle this on success: function(data){} ? Jquery notification message would be better for my scenario. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `success:function(){ alert('Successfully posted'); },error:function(){ alert('Unable to post'); }` (or something of the sort).

Comment: This is working for me. Thanks for that. But if I want to display some Jquery flash message how can I do that ?

Comment: On what object? The body? `$('<p>',{text:'Post successful!'}).appendTo('body')` That would add a success message to the main document.

Comment: jquery flash message in fact

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by flash message. This may be better suited for a new question (where you can supply more detail and explain the problem more clearly). As it is, we've gotten the AJAX request to work and `alert()` the user. A 'jquery flash mesage' can mean a lot of different things, and without some HTML to see it's hard to give you an answer.